# Ignoring punctuation in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am working on a Caeser cipher encryptor with JavaScript for a university project and have so far managed to get it working fine.

The only problem is, I need to retain the punctuation ( ,!, ? etc) after encryption and I'm having difficulties. Here is my current code:

```js
function encryptor() {
  var alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
  var letter = "";
  var encWord = "";
  var userInput = document.getElementById("message").value;
  var key = parseInt(window.prompt("Enter a key:"));

  for (i = 0; i < userInput.length; i++) {
    letter = userInput[i];

    var shift = alphabet.indexOf(letter);

    if (letter.match("/[^A-Za-z0-9_]/")) {
      continue;
    } else if (shift < 23) {
      var encLetter = alphabet[shift + key];
    } else {
      var encLetter = alphabet[shift - (26 - key)];
    }

    encWord += encLetter;
  }

  document.getElementById("encWord").innerHTML = encWord;
}
```

Could anyone please point me in the right direction please?

Thanks.

Comment: You don't add punctuation to your final string.

Comment: you could add punctuation as written word, like `questionmark` and take it as well for encryption. later search for that word and replace it with the sign. to distinguish it from a given word, you could add some additional letters in front like `qq` or what ever might be handy.

Comment: @SergeK. I'm not sure what you mean. The user inputs a message into a form field, this could contain some punctuation. The letters of the message gets shifted however many places along the alphabet the user decides. The end result needs to show the encrypted message but with the punctuation still intact.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before the `continue` you should add `letter` to `encWord`

```
if (letter.match(/[^A-Za-z0-9_]/)) {
    encWord += letter;
    continue;
}
```

Otherwise it will just skip it.

Comment: This makes a lot of sense, but doesn't work. It seems that when I'm putting in punctuation, whether that's a whitespace or ! or ?, they're being outputted as the letter a. so "abc def" with a shift of 2 is outputting "cdebfgh"

Comment: @Archer Thanks! Simply removing the quotes from the regular expression worked. My mistake

Comment: @Archer copy-pasted too quickly from the question. Thanks for noticing

Answer (score 0):

For keepint the punctuation, you could check, if the character is in the alphabe string and if not, then use the punctuation for this item.

```js
function encryptor() {
    var alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz",
        letter,
        encWord = "",
        userInput = document.getElementById('message').value,
        key = parseInt(window.prompt("Enter a key:")),
        shift,
        i;
  
    for (i = 0; i < userInput.length; i++) {
        letter = userInput[i];
        shift = alphabet.indexOf(letter);
        if (shift === -1) {
            encWord += letter;
            continue;
        }
        encWord += alphabet[(shift + key) % alphabet.length];
    }
    document.getElementById("encWord").innerHTML = encWord;
}
```

```html
<input id="message" type="text" onchange="encryptor()"><br>
<div id="encWord"></div>
```

Comment: Nice code, but a little wonky if you go below index zero

Comment: Thanks for this answer, some shorthand code that I wasn't aware of.

Comment: @EmilS.Jørgensen, it's all well defined.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method would be to maintain an "alphabet" and simply shift along it, using `indexOf` to get each symbols location.

Here is an implementation:

```js
var caesarCipher = (function() {
  var alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!"#¤%&/()=?`½§@£$€{[]}|\'*';
  return function caesarCipher(message, offset) {
    if (offset === void 0) {
      offset = 1;
    }
    return message.replace(/./igm, function(letter) {
      if (alphabet.indexOf(letter) >= 0) {
        return alphabet[((alphabet.indexOf(letter) + offset) + alphabet.length) % alphabet.length];
      }
      return letter;
    });
  };
})();
//TEST
var chipherOffset = 7;
var message = "Hello World.";
caesarCipher(message, chipherOffset);
console.log(caesarCipher(message, chipherOffset));
console.log(caesarCipher(caesarCipher(message, chipherOffset), 0 - chipherOffset));
```

Notice how i "forgot" to add `.` to my alphabet. That is the risk you run when maintaining your own alphabet.

Another solution would be to use `charCodeAt` and `String.fromCharCode` and simply use the build-in alphabet already in the browser:

```js
var caesarCipher = (function () {
    var alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789!"#¤%&/()=?`½§@£$€{[]}|\'*';
    return function caesarCipher(message, offset) {
        if (offset === void 0) { offset = 1; }
        return message.replace(/./igm, function (letter) {
            return String.fromCharCode(letter.charCodeAt(0) + offset);
        });
    };
})();
//TEST
var chipherOffset = 7;
var message = "Hello World.";
caesarCipher(message, chipherOffset);
console.log(caesarCipher(message, chipherOffset));
console.log(caesarCipher(caesarCipher(message, chipherOffset), 0 - chipherOffset));
```

This solution fixes the "forgot-to-add-symbol" issue, but you risk getting some very weird symbols like "\n", which can really mess your strings up!

Comment: @NickA .. Dangit ^^ Also, fixed!